# New errors when trying to export from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, upload

me and my friend just finished our application, with no errors. We were just going to export it from eclipse to our google account. But before being able to, it stopped us, saying that we had to fix the errors before uploading. The errors started to appear, on every .java file.

Every error is referring to "type".
For instance:
Bundle cannot resolve to type
Activity cannot be resolved to a type
I have attached a link to a file which shows the issue (its like that on every .java file

http://fuskbugg.se/dl/VAYBSP/asd.png

Here is a part of the manifest, since the body is limited to 30 000 characters, and our manifest is about 87 000:

```
enter code here
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.brottsbalken3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para5" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para6"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para6" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para7"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para7" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para21"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para21" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para22"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para22" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para23"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para23" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para24"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para24" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para25"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para25" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para25A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para25" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para26"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para26" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para27"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para27" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para27A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para27" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para27B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para27_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para27C"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para27_c" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para28"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para28" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para23A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para23" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para31"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para31" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para32"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para32" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para33"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para33" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para34"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para34" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para35"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para35" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para36"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para36" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para37"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para37" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para38"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para38" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para39"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para39" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para310"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para310" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para311"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para311" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para312"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para312" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para313"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para313" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap2del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap2del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap3del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap3del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para41"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para41" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para42"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para42" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para43"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para43" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para43A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para43" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para43B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para43_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para44"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para44" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para45"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para45" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para46"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para46" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap4del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap4del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para41A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para41" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para47"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para47" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para48"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para48" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para48A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para48" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para48B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para48_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para49C"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para49_c" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para48C"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para48_c" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para49"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para49" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para410"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para410" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap5" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para51"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para51" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para52"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para52" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para53"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para53" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para54"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para54" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para55"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para55" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap6"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap6" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para61"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para61" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para62"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para62" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para63"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para63" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para64"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para64" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para65"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para65" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para66"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para66" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para67"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para67" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para68"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para68" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap6del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap6del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para69"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para69" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para610"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para610" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para611"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para611" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para612"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para612" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para613"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para613" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para614"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para614" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para615"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para615" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para610A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para610" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap7"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap7" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para71"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para71" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para72"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para72" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para73"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para73" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para74"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para74" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para75"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para75" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para76"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para76" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap8"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap8" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para81"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para81" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para82"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para82" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para84"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para84" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para85"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para85" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para86"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para86" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para87"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para87" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para88"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para88" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para89"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para89" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap8del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap8del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para810"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para810" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para810A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para810" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para811"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para811" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para812"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para812" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para813"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para813" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap9"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap9" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para91"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para91" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para92"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para92" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para93"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para93" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para93A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para93" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para94"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para94" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para95"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para95" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para96"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para96" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para96A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para96" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap9del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap9del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para97"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para97" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para97A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para97" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para98"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para98" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para99"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para99" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para910"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para910" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para911"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para911" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para912"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para912" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap10"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap10" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para101"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para101" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para102"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para102" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para103"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para103" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para104"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para104" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105C"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105_c" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap10del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap10del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105D"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105_d" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para105E"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para105_e" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para106"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para106" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para107"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para107" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para108"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para108" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para109"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para109" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para1010"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para1010" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap11"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap11" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para111"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para111" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para112"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para112" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para113"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para113" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para114"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para114" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para115"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para115" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para116"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para116" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para117"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para117" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para118"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para118" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap12"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap12" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para121"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para121" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para122"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para122" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para123"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para123" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para124"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para124" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para125"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para125" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para126"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para126" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap13"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap13" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para131"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para131" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para132"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para132" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para133"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para133" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para134"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para134" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para135"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para135" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para135A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para135" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para135B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para135_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para136"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para136" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap13del2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap13del2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para137"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para137" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para138"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para138" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Para139"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_para139" >
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: Looks like your project lost a reference to your Android library. Try looking at the "Problems" View (Windows>Show View>Problems)

Comment: http://fuskbugg.se/dl/nL80x0/problemos.png

those are the problems shown, also already tried to clean the project, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest got messed up. That's why the errors talk about

> the markup before the root element

When you tried to upload it to the App Engine, Eclipse reconfigured your application to be compatible with that environment! You'll need to recreate your project as an Android App and skip the part where you try to upload it to the App Engine.

Look at [this site](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html) to see what steps you need to take to publish an Android App.

Comment: That is just some spaces that came when I made the post, they are not there in the manifest. Any other ideas?

Comment: http://fuskbugg.se/dl/4udCsS/Nospaces.png 

As I stated above, there are no spaces in the manifest, I added them by mistake when I made the post.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but I really dont see any problems.
This is how the manifest starts:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Doesnt seem to be any problems here?

Comment: Ok i have tracked down the issue to "no grammar constraints (dtd or xml schema) detected for the document", now what?

Comment: The first line of your manifest is wrong. You have encoding="utf-8?>" It should be encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: The issue still remains though, every line of coding in the .java part is referring to an error. blabla cant resolve to a type

Comment: where is the bin directory?

Comment: i found several bin directories, one of them contained "AndroinedManifest.XML"

Comment: it does not differ from the one i have in my project

Comment: I honestly can't help you much more, then. From the errors it seems you have a mistake in your Manifest, but since you're unable to post it completely, I can't really help you anymore. A tip, though: in all your activities you put android:name="com.example.brottsbalken3.Kap1" and you could shorten this to android:name=".Kap1"

Comment: Can i restore my project to a specific time?

Comment: can you tell me where i find Appcfg.cmd? thanks for all your help

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp it's in appengine-java-sdk/bin . But if you're publishing an Android application, you need to do it at https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/

Comment: Look at my amended answer. I think I see why you're having trouble now.